# How to assign a "null" value from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I would like to create a new column called "season_new", where I want to maintain the non-null season and extract the season for null values from the programme name. My dataframe is something like this:

| programme | season |
| --- | --- |
| grey's anatomy s1 | null |
| friends season 1 | 1 |
| grey's anatomy s2 | null |
| big bang theory s2 | 2 |
| big bang theory | 1 |
| peaky blinders | 1 |

I'd try using regex.

`dt['season_new'] = dt['programme'].str.extract(r'(season\s?\d+|s\s?\d+)')`

But it gave me this result:

| programme | season | season_new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| grey's anatomy s1 | null | 1 |
| friends season 1 | 1 | 1 |
| grey's anatomy s2 | null | 2 |
| big bang theory s2 | 2 | 2 |
| big bang theory | 1 | null |
| peaky blinders | 1 | null |

The result that I expected is:

| programme | season | season_new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| grey's anatomy s1 | null | 1 |
| friends season 1 | 1 | 1 |
| grey's anatomy s2 | null | 2 |
| big bang theory s2 | 2 | 2 |
| big bang theory | 1 | 1 |
| peaky blinders | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

I think that the easiest way to do this is using the `apply()` method. I also used Regex

I first tried this, using a piece of your code:

```py
data['season_new'] = data.apply(lambda x: x.season if pd.notna(x.season) else re.search(r'(season\s?\d+|s\s?\d+)',x.programme).group(1), axis=1)
```

The output was this:

```
             programme   season  season_new
0    grey's anatomy s1      NaN          s1
1     friends season 1      1.0         1.0
2    grey's anatomy s2      NaN          s2
3   big bang theory s2      2.0         2.0
4      big bang theory      1.0         1.0
5       peaky blinders      1.0         1.0
```

As we can see the column season_new is not a 100% correct. So i tried in another way:

```py
data['season_new'] = data.apply(lambda x: x.season if pd.notna(x.season) else (x.programme[-1] if x.programme[-1].isdigit() else np.nan), axis=1).astype('int')
```

The expected output:

```
             programme   season  season_new
0    grey's anatomy s1      NaN           1
1     friends season 1      1.0           1
2    grey's anatomy s2      NaN           2
3   big bang theory s2      2.0           2
4      big bang theory      1.0           1
5       peaky blinders      1.0           1
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying your code, for some reason the regex didn't return only the integers:

```
0   grey's anatomy s1     NaN         s1
1    friends season 1     1.0   season 1
2   grey's anatomy s2     NaN         s2
3  big bang theory s2     2.0         s2
4     big bang theory     1.0        NaN
5      peaky blinders     1.0        NaN
```

I am not so great at regex so looked into another option which is below.

```
df = pd.read_excel(source_file)

# Empty list for data capture
season_data = []

# Loop thought all rows
for idx in df.index:

    # Grab value to check
    check_val = df["season"][idx]

    # If value is not null then keep it
    if pd.notnull(check_val):

        # Add value to list
        season_data.append(int(check_val))

    else:
        # Extract digits from programme description
        extract_result = "".join(i for i in df["programme"][idx] if i.isdigit())

        # Add value to list
        season_data.append(extract_result)

# Add full list to dataframe
df["season_new"] = season_data

print(df)
```

Result is:

```
            programme  season season_new
0   grey's anatomy s1     NaN          1
1    friends season 1     1.0          1
2   grey's anatomy s2     NaN          2
3  big bang theory s2     2.0          2
4     big bang theory     1.0          1
5      peaky blinders     1.0          1
```

Answer (score -1):

use following code:

```
pat = r'[season|s]\s?(\d+$)'
df.assign(season_new=df['season'].fillna(df['programme'].str.extract(pat)[0]))
```

result:

```
programme          season   season_new
grey's anatomy s1   NaN     1
friends season 1    1       1
grey's anatomy s2   NaN     2
big bang theory s2  2       2
big bang theory     1       1
peaky blinders      1       1
```